# XCode Allocation Tool indicates a High allocation count for UIWebView created in table Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, memory-management

I checked the allocation tool and found the following:

[image]

What does the line in dark purple mean? Does it mean that setting a UIWebview in a UITableCell is using up lots of memory - 1.58 MB (during allocation)? Also it seems that the memory usage keeps increasing for the setting of youtube webview.

Is this a real cause for concern? If yes, what can I do to reduce the amounts of allocatin required for this?